# Failure when using XMR Stak CPU Miner on Linux

Tags: development, cpu-mining

I recently set up XMR-Stak-CPU Miner on my Linux system, and, as listed as a common occurrence in the README (located [here](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/blob/master/README.md#common-issues)), the program failed with the "MEMORY ALLOC FAILED: mmap failed" exit code. I performed the steps required to fix the error as recommended in the README (**without** logging off and back on as is necessary for changes to take effect), and the program began to work. Later on, after logging off and logging back in, I noticed the miner would once again not start and gave me the same "MEMORY ALLOC FAILED" error in spite of me already performing the fix.

I have no idea what could be causing the program to fail after successfully working for a full day without problem. I have tried changing the /etc/security/limits.conf file back to the original without success.

Any and all suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems (after some troubleshooting and a few direct messages to the author of XMR-Stak-CPU, /u/fireice_uk on reddit) that I've found the solution:

As it turns out, the `sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=128` command that must be run to fix the "MEMORY ALLOC FAILURE" error must be run every boot.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of running the sysctl command every boot do this:
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
and add "vm.nr_hugepages=128" to the bottom of the file.

Credit to CryptocurrencyFreak for this (https://www.cryptocurrencyfreak.com/2017/08/22/monero-mining-xmr-stak-cpu-ubuntu-16-04/)